# elif statement not working as expected

Tags: python, if-statement, comparison

I'm trying to look through multiple sources to see which one has a specific entry.

My input looks like:

```
json_str2 = urllib2.urlopen(URL2).read()
u = json.loads(json_str2)
#load all five results
One = u['flightStatuses'][0]
Two = u['flightStatuses'][1]
Three = u['flightStatuses'][2]
Four = u['flightStatuses'][3]
Five = u['flightStatuses'][4]
```

My `if` statement works correctly and I get the correct result:

```
if One['flightNumber'] == str(FlEnd):
    fnumber = One['flightId']
    print fnumber
```

But when I add the `elif:` the answer is wrong (nothing) even when the first statement is `True`.

I don't understand why the `elif` doesn't work?

```
# if statement checks each result to define flightId, needed for tracking.
if One['flightNumber'] == str(FlEnd):
    fnumber = One['flightId']
elif Two['flightNumber'] == str(FlEnd):
    fnumber = Two['flightId']
print fnumber
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your condition; something else is going on.

Comment: Thanks and I'll ensure I am formatting correctly in future. One['flightNumber'] does equal str(FlEnd) and Two['flightNumber'] does not.. am I missing something really obvious? - It seems to be overwriting fnumber?

Answer (score 3):

You should write this as a loop over the five flight statuses instead of using five variables and five conditions.

```
results = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(URL2).read())['flightStstuses']
for result in results:
    if result['flightNumber'] == str(FlEnd):
        fnumber = result['flightId']
        break
else:
    fnumber = None
print fnumber
```

Comment: if result['flightNumber'] == str(FlEnd):
TypeError: string indices must be integers (the data in these 5 results can be a bit messy)

Comment: Yep, my bad. Forgot to get the flightStatuses key.